# having a hard time using printf in java and reading errors in eclipse

Tags: java, printf

```
public class TryMyMath {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        double num = Math.E;
        printTable(num);
    }// end main

    public static void printTable(double num){
        int n = 1;

        for(n = 1;n <= 10; n++)
        {
            num = Math.pow(num, n);
            System.out.printf("%d %lf", n, num);
        }
        round100th(num);

    }
    public static double round100th(double num)
    {
        return Math.round(num*100.)/100.0 ;
    } // end round100th

}
```

i have this question with using printf in java, so this is the error i get with printf

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'l'
  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
  at TryMyMath.printTable(TryMyMath.java:15)
  at TryMyMath.main(TryMyMath.java:7)
```

when i take out printf statement there wasn't any error, am I not using printf the right way it is supposed to be used in java?

and also i'm new to java and eclipse so i don't know what those error mean.

so this is the out put that i get

1
 2.7182822 
7.3890563 
403.4287934
 26489122129.8434375
 13041808783936237000000000000000000000000000000000000.0000006
 Infinity7 
Infinity8
 Infinity9 
Infinity10 
Infinity

the output is only  right up to n = 3  i don't see anything wrong with the for loop why is this happen?

nvm i saw what wrong with it

Comment: You come from C? "%f" works for double in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `System.out.printf("%d %f", n, num)`. The `l` is meaningless here.

Additionally, your `round100th(num);` call has no effect - are you trying to print the numbers to two decimal places? You can do that with:

```
System.out.printf("%d %.2f", n, num)
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [String Formatter Conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), there is no `%l`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about this, but I believe in java you only have to use

> System.out.printf(n + " " + num)

It's been awhile though, so you'll need to check it. Please tell me if I'm wrong. I don't want to leave an incorrect answer up.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.out.printf("%d %f", n, num);
```

The [formatting is described in great in JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

> System.out.printf("%d %lf", n, num);

%lf is not appropriate.  Did you mean %1f?  Notice that the former has a lowercase "L" and the latter has a "1".  Try it with a 1 and it should work.

Comment: "The problem is with this line:" - congratulations, you can read a stack trace - `TryMyMath.java:15`

Comment: oh i was thinking in c where you use %lf for double